# blenderkit addon blocked

Tags: blenderkit

okay, I'm working on a project, and I needed quick access to free trees. to get them, I need blender kit. well when I downloaded it, it was set up as just a file. and in order to make it a zip file, I have to compress it. but when I try to compress it, it gives me this notification [image]

I understand this is more of a computer problem, but I can't find anything online about how to fix this, so I came here.
(blender kit also does not show up in the preferences + addons menu)

Comment: You may find more information on the github issue tracker https://github.com/BlenderKit/blenderkit/issues

Comment: If you download Blenderkit from blenderkit.com,  ou end up with the latsest version addon in a zip-file. No need to decompress, just install in Blender and you're good to go. It looks like you are trying to compress an update-file, i don't think there's a need to use that file.

Comment: @Jaco unfortunately the downloaded zip file gets automatically decompressed by the Safari browser.

Comment: Try to press the Alt key when you click the download link to stop the decompressing. Here is an old question about this. It seems still to work. Check the lastest comments below the answers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/961/how-to-stop-safari-from-unzipping-files-after-download

Comment: Then in the preferences, uncheck the box where it says something like "open "safe" files after downloading". That way you download the zip without opening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Safari browser is automatically extracting the archives. To get over this feature, you can:

- hold the ⌥ alt button while clicking on the download link,
- right click on the link and select "Download linked files"

Then Safari should download the zip file without extracting, so you can then install it directly in the Blender without any need to touch the ZIP.

Comment: If you forget to do the above and safari has unzipped your files, go to the finder and right-click on the top-level folder. Pick "Compress <foldername>". It will recreate a zip file at the same location as the top folder.  Don't forget to delete the expanded folder and files.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from the site developer:

The solution should be displayed right above the download button on the [Get BlenderKit](https://www.blenderkit.com/get-blenderkit/) page:
[image]

If this message is not displayed in Safari browser, it is bug on our site, can you please write exact Safari/MacOS versions if this happens?

Also if somebody knows a solution how to tell Safari not to extract the file it would be very appreciated.